# How to get rid of a green plus icon as you do drag and drop in Cocoa?

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop

I'm curious if there is a way to get rid of a green plus icon that appears on drag and drop operation in cocoa? Is there any methods to disable it?!

Comment: The green plus icon indicates that the item is going to be copied; it doesn't appear if it's going to be moved. This is a good thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by using NSDragOperationMove instead of copy:

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingUpdated:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender
{
    return NSDragOperationMove;
}
```